# Is there any way to make Nextion screen gauge needle show the passed sector of the circle?

Tags: nextion

I am trying to do circle with needle (gauge) using Nextion screen but i need to show the passed area in the circle when the needle start moving then i remove it when some button is pressed the problem is the nextion screen doesn't have this feature in its editor so **is there a way to design my custom gauge that leaves some colored area behind when moves** ?

Thank you for reading my question I appreciate your help.

I thought of adding many pictures every single one of them shows one angle sector in some color but I'm not sure if this method is efficient as long as we need to add 360 (angles) pictures and organize them in true shape.

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported range property in gauge component in nextion.
See [documentation](https://nextion.tech/editor_guide/)